# PHP AJAX Delete Record - deletion only works 1 time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am deleting records with ajax and php. When I click the button it erases the record but when I click to delete another record it does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

HTML

```
<form id="prop_remove">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="last_id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="user" id="last_user" value="<?php echo $user; ?>">
    <input type="button" name="submit" id="last_prop" class="button fullwidth margin-top-5" value="Delete">
</form>
```

AJAX

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#last_prop').click(function() {
        var id = $('#last_id').val();
        var user = $('#last_user').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "delete.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                ilan_id: id,
                ilan_user: user
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if (response == 1) {
                    $('#last_prop').closest('tr').css('background', 'tomato');
                    $('#last_prop').closest('tr').fadeOut(800, function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                } else {
                    alert('Invalid id');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    require_once 'config.php';
    $id     =  $_POST['ilan_id'];
    $user   =  $_POST['ilan_user'];

    $checkRecord    = "SELECT * FROM last_tbl WHERE id = '$id' AND user = '$user'";
    $check_result   = mysqli_query($conn, $checkRecord);
    $totalrows      = mysqli_num_rows($check_result);

    if($totalrows > 0){
        $delete_sql     =   "DELETE FROM last_tbl WHERE id = '$id' AND user = '$user';";
        $delete_result  =   mysqli_query($conn, $delete_sql);
        echo 1;
        exit;
    }

?>
```

Comment: Add a console.log at click function and check, if it gets called the second time.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? There might be simpler ways of doing it. Its not working because you don't set new values for `last_user` and `last_id` inputs when deleting.

Comment: The values of `$user` and `$id` are hard-wired into the code. So when you click the button a second time it tries to delete the same record, which fails.

Comment: @wuarmin i will try thanks

Comment: @Dharman thanks i know but my question is not related to this.

Comment: @Qirel each record button is different. each record has its own button and different value is sent. but when a record is deleted the other buttons do not work.

Comment: Precisely - because you overwrite the IDs. You can't re-use IDs in HTML elements.

Comment: As mentioned, its absolutely vulnerable to sql injection as when you try to delete the same record again, it is not actually there in the db. So i suggest you to check if the record exists or not, before deleting the record. If it does exists, then its fine. Also you should start using prepared statements which are safe from SQL Injection (as long as you aren't just doing unsafe things elsewhere (that is constructing SQL statements by string concatenation))

Comment: @jitendra-ahuja sql injection protection is available in my original code. There are multiple records in the database. The button for a recording is running and deleting the recording. The other buttons do not work after the deletion is complete. this is the only problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're overwriting the HTML element IDs. You can remove your forms and use a single button instead, and pass data through the `data` attribute of the buttons.

Replace your form by a single button

```php
<button class="button fullwidth margin-top-5 last_prop" data-last-id="<?= $id; ?>" data-last-user="<?= $user; ?>">Delete</button>
```

Then adapt your jQuery to use the class `last_prop` instead of the ID, and fetch the values from the `data` attributes we set above.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.last_prop').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).data('last-id');
        var user = $(this).data('last-user');

        $.ajax({
            url:"delete.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {ilan_id: id, ilan_user: user},
            success:function(response){
                if (response == 1 ){
                    $('#last_prop').closest('tr').css('background','tomato');
                    $('#last_prop').closest('tr').fadeOut(800,function(){
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                } else {
                    alert('Invalid id');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Also, your query can be reduced to one (you don't need that `SELECT`), and should be with a prepared statement.

```php
<?php
    require_once 'config.php';
    $id     =  $_POST['ilan_id'];
    $user   =  $_POST['ilan_user'];

    $sql = "DELETE FROM last_tbl WHERE id = ? AND user = ?;";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $id, $user);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->affected_rows) {
        // rows were deleted
        echo 1;
    }
    $stmt->close();
```